# Why does my website give 404 errors on html pages only? if I create the same page in PHP then it works

Tags: php, html, iis

I have a website which is written in php.
For various reasons, one of my pages on my website needs to be a html page, the problem is when ever I use a html extension it gives a 404 error, yet, if I create the same page with  a PHP extension then it works fine.

however I can access the html locally

for example ... file://192.168.1.3/Data/websites/testsite/test.html.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is probably a webserver thing. Are you perhaps using Apache, and do you have some rewrite rules in .htaccess? Or do you have another webserver?

Comment: It is ISS on server 2012 R2, I am using the web.config for the rules such as the mimi types. I do have a few websites running on there and have just tested the html extension on those and they all have the same issue, I am not using .htaccess

Comment: I add the IIS tag to your question. I know nothing about this webserver, but this way people that do might see your question.

Comment: You need to reveal IIS settings such as how you configured PHP on it. If you follow the official guide from Microsoft, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php#zip-file-installation then `.html` files are handled by IIS and 404 shouldn't occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I managed to find a typo in the

`<staticContent> <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html" /> </staticContent>`

the "t" was missing like so ... `<staticConten>`